# Why does `imshow` display a 2D (non-RGB) array in color, and how can I export such a color image to a .png file?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I generated a Mandelbrot figure as 10000x10000 pixel numpy array:

```
[[ 100.  100.  100. ...,   12.   12.   13.]
 [ 100.  100.  100. ...,   12.   13.   14.]
 [ 100.  100.  100. ...,   12.   12.   14.]
 ..., 
 [   3.    3.    3. ...,    3.    3.    3.]
 [   3.    3.    3. ...,    3.    3.    3.]
 [   3.    3.    3. ...,    3.    3.    3.]]
```

If I show the array using matplotlib:

```
arr = np.zeros((10000, 10000)) # my array
import matplotlib.pyplot at plt
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```

I get a really nice colored image.

But ***why***?

In addition to this, if I try to export it to `.png` I get a *black and white* image:

```
import PIL.Image as im
iimg = im.fromarray(arr)
iimg = iimg.convert("RGB") # std was "F", but it didn't work
iimg.save("img_mandelbrot.png")
```

[image: with matplotlib]

[image: exported via PIL]

*Is there a way of exporting such a coloured image to png?*
 matplotlib does not seem to be a viable option, as the resolution is too bad.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. Most matplotlib 2D plotting routines return really nice colored images :) So does `imshow`; unless you provide the actual color for each point (a `MxNx3` [RGB] or `MxNx4` [RGBA] ), a 2D array is simple colored based on the values of the array.

Comment: See [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

Comment: @julbra see my edit.

Comment: Why is the resolution with matplotlib "too bad"? `savefig()` has a `dpi` keyword, so combining the figure size with the right dpi, you could save it with as much detail as you want?

Comment: @julbra thank you, I did not think of this, ( I am using `matplotlib.pyplot.imsave` ), provide it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, `savefig` has a `dpi` option

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) #
arr = np.random.random((10000,10000)) # my array
plt.imshow(arr)

plt.savefig('fig.png', dpi=1000)
```

I can't post the original PNG (it's about 200 megabyte), but this gives you as much detail as you want. Some zoomed screenshots of the output from the script above:

[image: zoom_1]
[image: zoom_2]

Note that this way the figure (incl. borders, axis labels, etc.) is 10000x10000 pixels, so you still won't see the actual 10000x10000 pixels from `arr` individually. The solution from ali_m with `imsave` indeed takes care of this problem, if you don't mind not having axis labels, titels, et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a 2D array to [`plt.imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), the intensity values are mapped to RGBA values. This is done according to a look-up table called the colormap, which can be specified via the `cmap=` keyword argument. For example, to plot your Mandelbrot array in grayscale you could select the `'gray'` colormap:

```
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')
```

If you don't pass the `cmap=` argument matplotlib will use whatever the default is, which you can also modify in your [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) file. For a clean installation of the current version of matplotlib, the default is a colormap called `'jet'`, which looks like this:

[image]

[`'jet'` is a pretty terrible colormap for many purposes](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/), and [will soon be replaced as the default colormap in matplotlib v2.0](http://matplotlib.org/style_changes.html#colormap). You can read more about selecting colormaps in the [official documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html).

You can also pass a 3D array to `imshow`, where the size of the final dimension is either 3 or 4. In this case the final dimension is interpreted as the RGB(A) value for each pixel. Since the color information is already contained within the array, no look-up table is needed and therefore the `cmap=` argument will be ignored.

---

To address the second part of your question, an easy way to save your array as a colormapped full-resolution `.png` image would be to use [`plt.imsave`](http://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imsave), which also takes a `cmap=` argument:

```
plt.imsave('mandelbrot.png', arr, cmap='jet')
```

`plt.imsave` just exports the raw pixels in the array, so a 10000x10000 input array will generate a `.png` image of exactly 10000x10000 pixels.

In contrast, [`plt.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) renders the whole figure canvas (including the margins, axes, other plot elements etc.), and scales this according to (1) the size of the figure in inches and (2) the `dpi=` keyword argument. Although you could achieve a high enough resolution just by setting the DPI to be much greater than you need, it would be much more difficult to render your array at actual size using this method, since you would need to fiddle around with the figure size and/or DPI, as well as the position and size of the axes etc.

Comment: thank you! ( I will wait for jubra posing an answer to accept hers).